# Google scatter chart for two arrays

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Hello People here is my Google scattered chart code what I am using:

```
require '/lib/GoogleChart.php';
require '/lib/markers/GoogleChartShapeMarker.php';
require '/lib/markers/GoogleChartTextMarker.php';

$Variance=array();
$Emp_RecFactor=array();
$Emp_Id=array();

//$Emp_FirstName=array();
$EquityGraph=new EquityGraph();
$EquityGraph->Graph();
$DrawGraph=$EquityGraph->DrawGraph;

foreach($DrawGraph as $key=>$value)
{
    $Variance[]=$value["Variance"];//for multiple values ,array
    $Emp_RecFactor[]=$value["Emp_RecFactor"];//single value
    $Emp_Id[]=$value["Emp_Id"];//single value
}

$_GET['Variance']=$Variance;
$_GET['Emp_RecFactor']=$Emp_RecFactor;

print_r($Emp_RecFactor);

$chart = new GoogleChart('lc', 500, 200);

// manually forcing the scale to [0,100]
$chart->setScale(0,100);

// add one line
$data = new GoogleChartData($Variance);
$chart->addData($data);

// customize y axis
$y_axis = new GoogleChartAxis('y');
$y_axis->setDrawTickMarks(false)->setLabels(array(-5,0,5));
$chart->addAxis($y_axis);

// customize x axis
$x_axis = new GoogleChartAxis('x');
$x_axis->setTickMarks(5);
$chart->addAxis($x_axis);

// add a shape marker with a border
$shape_marker = new GoogleChartShapeMarker(GoogleChartShapeMarker::CIRCLE);
$shape_marker->setSize(6);
$shape_marker->setBorder(2);
$shape_marker->setData($data);
$chart->addMarker($shape_marker);

// add a value marker
$value_marker = new GoogleChartTextMarker(GoogleChartTextMarker::VALUE);
$value_marker->setData($data);
$chart->addMarker($value_marker);

//~ header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $chart->toHtml();
```

As you can see in the code I have used `$Variance` array passing to `$data` now I need to use one more array `$Emp_RecFactor` and I need to draw a graph between those two...

I also want to add mouse over feature to this so that if someone hovers over the selected point it should display different things for different selected points -how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a Google scattered chart between two arrays you have to use code as below

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Array1', 'Array2'],
    [8, 12, 15],
    [4, 5.5, 0],
    [11, 0, 14],
    [4, 9, 5],
    [3, 3.5, 9],
    [6.5, 7, 13]
]);
```

And it has a default tooltip to show the data while hovering the selected point. We can also customize Tooltip content by using html tags.
To view a working sample for this go to the site [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-use-two-arrays-in-google-scattered-chart-and-draw-a-graph-between-those-two-arrays/)(Sample) and a customization of Tooltip content go to the site [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-customize-tooltip-text-using-html-tags-in-google-charts/)(customizing Tooltip)

Comment: this was my old question, anyways thanks alot for you answer 
Swarna Latha :)